# Camera of AR Application flipped in Vuzix M300 glasses

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, vuzix, vuzixm100

I am trying to install an AR application build using unity and Vuforia to vuzix m3000 glasses, but the camera of the application is flipped vertically and the contains of the screen is in the right way. I have tried to rotate the AR camera in unity but the view in the glasses is still flipped. Is there any other way to correct the camera view?

Answer (score 0):

I've run across a similar problem before; in my case, it was the HoloLens.

Try disabling MSAA on your camera object.

Essentially the post processing effect (the antialiasing in this case) messes with the camera's UVs and they get flipped (because one thing has the V=0 at the top, the other has V=0 at the bottom). [It's a long-standing](https://forum.unity.com/threads/since-the-latest-update-of-unity-or-hololens-everything-is-upside-down.465884/) problem [across multiple platforms](https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/896/upside-down-image-details-inside).